# Optimizing single-row DELETEs from a table with many FOREIGN KEY references

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, foreign-key, delete

In a database I am working on, there is a table called `persons` with about one million rows, and 60 FK (FK) constraints from other tables (some with many millions rows) pointing to it.

If I delete one row from `persons`, it takes many minutes, which would not be a problem, but it also keeps the table locked, thus blocking the database for all processes. In the past, this has caused users to report that the system is down.

Of course the situation would greatly improve if I added supporting indexes for all the FKs (currently, only 20 of the 60 tables have it). But many of these FKs are for columns like `modified_by`, so all the indexes would have no other purpose, and would degrade performance of the system in the daily operations, only to gain an improvement in an exceptional case.

Before running the DELETE, I already make sure that all the referencing rows have been deleted or updated. I do it manually, since I am strongly against the use of CASCADE.

I am not considering soft-delete because otherwise I would have to change all software that reads the `persons` table to skip deleted rows.

#### Question

Is there a way to (possibly temporarily) change the locking mechanism of the `persons` table, so that even if the DELETE takes an hour, it does not impact concurrent processes?

[Here's the anonymized execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BypcKakyr).

#### Considerations

- Disabling FKs might be a possibility. The risk is that someone else creates inconsistency while I delete the row, then I cannot re-enable the FKs.
- Rows to delete: typically one at a time. Either manual operation or scheduled.
- Interesting point: I did not check the execution plan immediately, but apparently, almost all operations cost 0%, except 7 cases of "Clustered index Scan (Clustered)" on the PK of referencing tables; one of them costs 57%, the other from 1% to 16%. I still don't understand why it should scan a clustered index.

Comment: Have you checked out SQLSentry Plan Explorer? You can anonymise the plans using it, it's free - if you use that and upload the plan we won't be able to see object names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94856/discussion-between-carlo-borreo-and-george-palacios).

Comment: "even if the DELETE takes an hour, it does not impact concurrent processes" Maybe snapshot isolation can help:
ALTER DATABASE <database name> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
But adding indexes on all foreign columns it the "correct" solution.

Comment: "Disabling FKs might be a possibility. The risk is that someone else creates inconsistency..." Not a problem if you do it in a transaction. Then you can disable all FKs, delete and re-enable FKs. But this does not help when deleting a single row. Now you get the delay during re-enable of FKs instead. It is possible to re-enable without checking integrity, but then the FKs become untrusted and queries _can_ be slower as the query optimizer will ignore untrusted FKs when making query plans. Disabling FKs only\mostly make sense when deleting more than 1 row.

Comment: "I still don't understand why it should scan a clustered index" It can if the clustered index contains more than 1 column, contains a column that reference persons table and this column is not the first column in the clustered index. Then it is still faster to scan the clustered index than to scan the table (but still slow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the situation would greatly improve if I added supporting indexes for all the FK (currently, only 20 of the 60 tables have it)

You should always index fields used as keys, foreign or otherwise. 
This gives the database far more options when analysing *how* to execute the query and adding them may actually increase the overall performance of your application.

> many of these FK are for columns like "modified by", so all the indexes would have no other purpose

As with [pretty much] everything on Planet Database, it's a compromise.
Here, you're balancing data integrity - knowing with certainty who changed something - against speed - not having those extra indexes that slow down inserts. 
Does it really matter if you don't know (with certainty) the user that changed these records?  If not, you're OK as you are.  If it *does* matter - and in lots of cases, it really, *really* does - then you're stuck with having the overhead of the indexes.

> Before running the DELETE, I already make sure that all the referencing records have been deleted ...

With the FK's in place, you would not be *able* to delete them anyway, so the values of this activity is dubious.

The question really should be, why is the delete *taking* an hour?
If you're only deleting one record out of a million row table and there are no rows in the tables with FK's back to this table, then what's taking the time?  It should be practically instantaneous.

Slow queries, even deletes, are often caused by missing indexes - are you performing the delete based on the record's Primary Key field?  Or some other combination of [not-indexed] fields?

Comment: I like your answer and upvoted.  The OP might be interested in this post about [Indexing for Deletes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/indexing-for-deletes/).